# Print Nested Object

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
import v20

ACCOUNT_ID = <my account id>
API_TOKEN = <my token>
SYMBOL = 'EUR_USD'
PRACTICE_STREAM_HOST = 'stream-fxpractice.oanda.com'
PORT = '443'


class Broker(object):
    def __init__(self):
        stream_host = PRACTICE_STREAM_HOST
        self.account_id = ACCOUNT_ID
        self.token = API_TOKEN
        self.stream_api = v20.Context(stream_host, PORT, token=API_TOKEN)

    def stream_prices(self, symbols=[]):
        response = self.stream_api.pricing.stream(
            self.account_id,
            instruments=",".join(symbols),
            snapshot=True
        )
        for msg_type, msg in response.parts():
            if msg_type == "pricing.ClientPrice":
                print(msg)

broker = Broker()
broker.stream_prices(symbols=[SYMBOL])
```

It outputs:

```
type: PRICE
instrument: EUR_USD
time: '2020-08-07T21:08:50.626707829Z'
status: non-tradeable
tradeable: false
bids:
- price: 1.17835
  liquidity: 10000000
asks:
- price: 1.17886
  liquidity: 10000000
closeoutBid: 1.17835
closeoutAsk: 1.17886
```

By changing the codes as below:

```
                print(msg.bids)
```

I get:

```
[<v20.pricing_common.PriceBucket object at 0x037E48E0>]
```

When I change it to:

```
                for x in msg.bids:
                    print(x)
```

I get:

```
price: 1.17835
liquidity: 10000000
```

I would like to be able to print the price with something like below to just return the bids - price:

```
                  print(msg.bids.price)
```

I can't seem to figure out that last little bit of code that I need.

Comment: `msg.bids` appears to be a list.  It doesn't *have* a `price`, that's an attribute of each individual element of the list.  So you need your `for` loop, just print `x.price` instead of just `x`.  Or use `print(msg.bids[0].price)`, if you know there's only one item.

Comment: @jasonharper or perhaps a dictionary? They are iterating over it, but it prints labels with the data.

Comment: @jasonharper x.price did it. As you can see I am new to python and still trying to make things harder than they need to be. Thank you.

Comment: I'm clearly new to python too and I've been using it for 3 years.
I don't know any advanced python stuff and yet I still use it lol.